# Gitlab-ci - Pipeline failing for no job

Tags: gitlab, yaml, gitlab-ci

Here is my `.gitlab-ci.yml` file:

```yaml
script1:
    only:
        refs:
            - merge_requests
            - master          
        changes:
            - script1/**/*
    script: echo 'script1 done'

script2:
    only:
        refs:
            - merge_requests
            - master
        changes:
            - script2/**/*
    script: echo 'script2 done'
```

I want `script1` to run whenever there is a change in `script1` directory; likewise `script2`.
I tested these with a change in `script1`, a change in `script2`, change in both the directories, and no change in either of these directories.

Former 3 cases are passing as expected but 4<sup>th</sup> case, the one with no change in either directory, is failing.

In the overview, Gitlab gives the message

`Could not retrieve the pipeline status. For troubleshooting steps, read the`[`documentation`](https://gitlab.com/help/user/project/merge_requests/reviewing_and_managing_merge_requests.md#troubleshooting)`.`

[image: Overview SS]

In the `Pipelines` tab, I have an option to `Run pipeline`. Clicking on that gives the error

`An error occurred while trying to run a new pipeline for this Merge Request.`

[image: Pipelines SS]

If there is no job, I want the pipeline to succeed.

Answer (score 1):

Gitlab pipelines do not have any independent validity outside of jobs. A pipeline, by definition, consists of one or more jobs. In your example 4 above no jobs are created. The simplest hack you can add to your pipeline is a job which always runs:

```
dummyjob:
    script: exit 0
```